# How to resize an image to fit multiple screen densities

Tags: android, android-image, android-screen-support

I need to add an avatar to a grid item.

I want to know how to handle the resizing of an image chosen from the phones gallery. Once chosen, I imagine some resizing will be needed, to fit it into the grid.

However, do I need to store a resized image for each screen density; store one xhdpi version and scale down for other devices, or be clever in some other way?

The reason is, the app stores this image to a cloud db and other people can download this image. They may see the image on different devices (hence the requirement of different image sizes). How should the managment of this image be processed?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you find the code below useful. It will return image with reqd dimensions with minimum overhead. I have used this many times, works like charm. You can set the required dimension according to target device. Scaling will cause blur in picture but this doesn't.

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(Uri uri) {                             
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 200000; // 0.2MP
        in = my_context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;                    //request only the dimesion
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
        in.close();

        int scale = 1;
        while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
            scale++;
        }

        Bitmap b = null;
        in = my_context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        if (scale > 1) {
            scale--;
            // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
            // larger than target
            o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inSampleSize = scale;
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            // resize to desired dimensions
            int height = b.getHeight();
            int width = b.getWidth();

            double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                    / (((double) width) / height));
            double x = (y / height) * width;

            Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x, (int) y, true);
            b.recycle();
            b = scaledBitmap;
            System.gc();
        } else {
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        }
        in.close();

        return b;
    } catch (IOException e) {

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll consider this as a resizing option.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Will scale an image and center it Size the Size a container to fill_parent with and it should do just that.

Comment: Interesting thanks. Looks like I could save the largest size image I require and use this to manage how it fits.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your images to drawable (without creating xhdpi,hdpi,mdpi,ldpi...) (global images).

Then you can create 4 same layouts for different screensizes . All of your layout can use the images in your drawable director. So you can resize your image easly.

Comment: I'm not planning on populating the res folders with pre done images. A user chooses an image from the gallery (like a picture of themself).

Comment: However it is the same logic. The picture which choosed by the user, can be resized in different layout which you have created. You can use android:scaleType="fitXY" to put your image on that image.

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY : If you use standart imageview size it can be useful. But different image view size ?? your image ratio will be breaked down. You can sol this problem by cropping image.android:scaleType="centerCrop"

Comment: Where would you stores these images on the device?

Comment: you can store your image in your internal memory

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader  you can look at this librar, it is very usefull